# from authorizenet.apicontrollers import createTransactionController :: ImportError: cannot import name requests

Tags: python-requests, importerror, authorize.net

I am using authorize.net python lib for making payment gateway. I am following this link:

**https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-python**

The code is like: `PaymentTransactions/charge-credit-card.py`

```
from authorizenet import apicontractsv1 <br>
from authorizenet.apicontrollers import createTransactionController <br>
def charge_credit_card(amount):<br>
    """
    Charge a credit card
    """
```

When I run this file, code throwing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File
>   "C:/development/learning/VueJsLearning/Payment-system/sample-code-python/PaymentTransactions/charge-credit-card.py", line 10, in 
>       from authorizenet.apicontrollers import createTransactionController   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\authorizenet\apicontrollers.py", line
>   9, in 
>       from authorizenet import apicontrollersbase 
>       File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\authorizenet\apicontrollersbase.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from pip._vendor import requests
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\requests__init__.py", line
>   83, in 
>       from pip._internal.compat import WINDOWS
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_internal__init__.py", line 42, in
>   
>       from pip._internal import cmdoptions
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cmdoptions.py", line 16,
>   in 
>       from pip._internal.index import (
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 15, in
>   
>       from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
>  ImportError: cannot import name requests

Comment: The package `requests` is not in your `PATH`. Install it into your virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks Steve!! I can see 'requests' package installed in my 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages' path. From some internet source I found that this issue is related to 'pip-10.0.1'. With 'pip-9' it works well. But I don't know why this issue is happening with 'pip10.0.1'.

Comment: Did you create a virtual environment? The path you provided is not your virtual environment, but your system path.